# Webpack 5 bundle React components library for browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am creating a library of react components and typescript to use in a web client application.
I want to bundle it excluding the packages in `node_modules`, with the imports in the bundle using UMD, as browsers does not understand commonjs.
I do not want to include the libraries in the bundle as I want to keep the final bundle sent to the browser as minimal as possible.

I may use  `webpack-node-externals` to avoid bundling the npm packages, but it is forcing Webpack to use commonjs in the bundle.

I have a minimal working example. Keep in mind that I may use many npm packages in this library, not just "react".

```
.
├── dist/
├── index.tsx
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.ts
```

**./package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "react-components",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.22",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

**./index.tsx**

```js
import React, { HTMLProps } from 'react';

interface Props extends HTMLProps<HTMLHeadingElement> {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const H1: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, ...props }) => <h1 {...props}>{children}</h1>;
```

**./tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": ["index.tsx"]
}
```

**./webpack.config.ts**

```js
import path from "path";
import nodeExternals from "webpack-node-externals";

module.exports = {
  entry: "./index.tsx",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), "dist"),
    clean: true,
  },
  target: "web",
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        use: ["ts-loader"],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```